# Android deployment issue

Tags: android-studio, genymotion

I have made changes to my app in android studio and deployed to genymotion emulator. But I am not able to see my changes in the app. 
I have tried cleaning and rebuilding the app and also disabled instant run but still my issue was not solved.

Answer (score 0):

Restart genymotion or try: Tools --> Android --> Sync Project with Gradle Files or read about similar problem on:
[Android Studio not deploying changes to app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312900/android-studio-not-deploying-changes-to-app)