# Android Studio 2.3 not deploying ui changes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

since today im not able to deploy my UI changes anymore. The app runs fine but i cant change anything on the UI side. Whatever I do the app keeps the same UI every time. I changed nothing since my last dev session and now im stuck with this problem for hours.

What I tried so far:

- Clean and Rebuild several Times
- Disabled Instant Run
- Deleted the Build folder
- Checked for different Layout versions
- Complete uninstall and reinstall of the app
- Gradle Sync
- Different Smartphones and Emulators

I can see all changes inside the preview of Android Studio but for some reason they dont appear in the deployed app.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_send_media);
```

Comment: share your java code where you are setting the content view.

Answer (score 0):

are you unable to see UI in XML?
then change the theme of the application,it may help you.

Comment: No inside Android Studio everything is fine. But I cant see the changes i made in the deployed app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312900/android-studio-not-deploying-changes-to-app check out this, it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

As you havent uploaded java file i am assuming This Might be your problem:
in your oncreate method please make sure that You havent used this by mistake

```
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        setContentView();
    }
```

it will persist your ui changes and wont update it.. so instead of this use following

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }
```

Comment: Added the code for completion but since I changed nothing it might not be the problem

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with a complete reinstall of Android Studio.