# Android studio 3.1 run command does not rebuild the APK

Tags: android, android-studio

This is very annoying aspect of the new android studio version 3.1, I used to launch run command after every code changes, the IDE rebuilds the (whole project & APK) and then deploys it on the target device.

Then after upgrading to version 3.1, the run command does not rebuild the apk any more, and displays the following error messages.

> android studio 3.1    Session 'app': Error Installing APK
>
> android studio 3.1  The APK file Error while Installing APK

so I have click on" rebuild & run" each time I make code modification, how can I restore the old behavior of version 3.0.1

Comment: Sounds like there might be a read/write permission issue. Have you tried restarted the IDE or even your entire OS?

Comment: Fix in android studio 3.1.1 Check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49746320/3806413 for details.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Go to `Run -> Edit configurations`. And then make sure you have `Gradle-aware Make` option like below screenshot.

[image]

If not then click `+` and select from the

More update in twitter regarding this:https://twitter.com/androidstudio/status/981914632892960768

Comment: thank you, it solved the issue !!

Comment: Had same issue. Thanks god for this answer :D

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me as well!

Comment: @MarcosDaSilva This is not issue this is feature! lol

Comment: NOT WORKING:
Shutdown finished in 0ms
Error while generating dependencies split APK
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
 at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:809)
 at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:797)
 at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunSplitApkBuilder.generateSplitApkResourcesAp(InstantRunSplitApkBuilder.java:373)

Comment: Disable instant run and then try again.

Comment: disabling instant run is not an answer, we all need it )))

Comment: @android51130 Check this answer also https://stackoverflow.com/a/49606137/3806413

Comment: For me, I removed "Instance App Provision" from Run -> Edit Configurations. Then it worked.

Answer (score -1):

disable the instant run option.
Open Settings from File > Settings
Navigate to Build,Execution,Deployment > Instant Run
Uncheck the enable instant run check box