# Android-Studio upgrade from 3.0.1 to 3.1.0 Debug/Run app failure

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.1

Yesterday I upgraded Android-Studio from 3.0.1 to 3.1.0 and found a problem with clicking Debug/Run app.

gradle version is upgraded from 3.0.1 to 3.1.0
buildToolsVersion version is upgraded 27.0.3

Gradle sync has been successful.

Every time you click the Debug app, as shown in Figure 1, there will be Error installing APK: Figure 2

[image: Clicking Debug app]

[image: Error status]

```
    //Error information
    03/28 15:40:41: Launching app
    The APK file/Users/hanson/myWork/android/nuttracker/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk does not exist on disk.
    Error while Installing APK


    //project root build.gradle file:
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
            google()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        }
    }
    allprojects {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation" << "-Xlint:unchecked"
        }
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            jcenter()
            maven {
                url 'https://maven.google.com/'
                name 'Google'
            }
            google()
        }
    }
    //app module dependencies library's version
    ext {
        compileSdkVersion = 26
        buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 18
        targetSdkVersion = 26

        // App dependencies
        gmsVersion = '11.8.0'
        supportLibraryVersion = '27.0.2'
        retrofitVersion = '2.3.0'
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The APK file does not exist on disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039834/the-apk-file-does-not-exist-on-disk)

Comment: you have to uninstall the existing app first, ( if you change the `buildToolsVersion` )

Comment: Thank Santanu Sur, I uninstall old app. The problem is solved.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49508278/3806413

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer of its own, not as an edit.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Santanu Sur, I uninstall old Android-Studio app. The problem is solved.