# Android Studio 3.1 issues

Tags: android, android-studio

Does anyone have such problems as:

1. Cannot install debug-apk because cannot find Application file, which exists in Androidmanifest.xml or:
   `The APK file /home/skullper/AndroidStudioProjects/app_pay/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk does not exist on disk.
   Error while Installing APK`

Of course I can fix this with `./gradlew assembleDebug`, but I should launch this each time before run, otherwise it will run only assembleDebug build

2. Issue with kotlin std in projects with Java only

When I was using 3.0 everything was ok and I haven't such issues. What should I do to run my project???

**UPDATE**

Everything works. Answer in comments under question.

Thank to all who was trying to help

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49508278/3806413

Comment: @0xalihn it's works. Up voted that answer

Comment: This question has already been answered and the link provided by 0xalihn has also been marked a duplicate of this post:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49505929/android-studio-3-1-run-not-compiling-code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio 3.1 "Run" not compiling code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49505929/android-studio-3-1-run-not-compiling-code)

Answer (score 0):

Try rebuilding your project and reinstall if nothing helps, I had this bug on my old computer and rebuilded helped.

Though if you reinstall Android Studio, make sure you delete the AVR folder properly! Otherwise the bits remaining from the previous version will alter the new installation completely useless.

Comment: I've tried already Rebuild, Clean and invalidateCache and restart, but it didn't help. My friend has the same issues with 3.1

Comment: Well I have 3.1 installed but don't get the issue. Something seems odd with the path but I'm out of ideas, try out @haythemsouissi 's idea.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to go to Android Studio's File menu and select Invalidate Caches / Restart... option, then restart Android Studio?

If so try this:

1- Remove the directory ~/.gradle/caches/. It's OK to do this while Android Studio is opened. (Refer pm installing wrong package name)

2- Press "Sync project with Gradle files" icon on Android Studio

3- Run the project and the remote path will be correct.

Comment: The error has been gone but new build has no newest changes. Studio running the build which was made with `./gradlew assembleDebug`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1 - Go to "Run/Debug configurations"

2 - In "Before launch" click in the "+"

3 - Add "Gradle-Aware Make"

4 - Click OK

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuHL9.png)

Hope it helps

Comment: Already do this. Comment under question helps me. But thank you