# Using Instant Run results in "Session app: Error while Installing APKs"

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, instant-run

I already tried:

**Turning off Instant Run -> Clean Build -> Turning on Again -> Run** as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38450717/session-app-error-while-installing-apk).

But cannot get it to work.
I **want** to use Instant Run and hence don't want to disable it. Please help me find out why this is happening.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49508278/3806413

Comment: @0xalihn I already have the `Gradle-aware Make` option added.

Comment: Can you just disable instant run and then check either it works or not?

Comment: I know it works on disabling Instant Run. But I don't want to. I have already mentioned that in the question.

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Run -> Edit configurations`. And then make sure you have `Instant App Provision` enable in addition with `Gradle-aware Make` option like below screenshot.

[image]

If not then click `+` and select from the list options.

Answer (score 0):

[image: See the image]

1. Click on Gradle (Right Side in Android Studio)
2. Click Refresh
3. Try Re-running the project.