# Error while assigning APK android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Everytime I run the android emulator there is an error assigning the APK
The log file

```
01:27   Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
01:27   Gradle build finished in 7s 956ms

01:28   Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: 
/data/app/vmdl776864964.tmp/11_app-debug signatures are inconsistent

01:28   Session 'app': Error Installing APKs
```

Do you guys know whats wrong?

Comment: Go to the project folder -> app. Then delete the build folder and rebuild it. This may solve the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50196679/6551653 Check the solution mentioned in the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Go to `File`> `Invalidate Caches/Restart` and `Clean Project`

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem in the past what I did is `Clean` the project and `Rebuild` it. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I have never had this kind of problem, mainly because I have never used Android Emulator, but I'll try to help as accurately as I can. Perhaps if you update it, it will work. Also, as a last resource you can just simply not use that file and use another one.
Hope it helps!