# Gradle sync failed: my project after update my Android studio from 3.0.1 to 3.1.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have just updated my Android studio from 3.0.1 to 3.1.0

I am getting this error when `Global Gradle setting` offline work is disabled

> Could not GET
>   'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/sun/xml/bind/mvn/jaxb-runtime-parent/2.2.11/jaxb-runtime-parent-2.2.11.pom'.
>   Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway Enable Gradle
>   'offline mode' and sync project

I tried enabling the `Global Gradle setting` offline work then this error occurs

> No cached version of org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.2.11 available
>   for offline mode. Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49505929/android-studio-3-1-gradle-unexpected-behaviour/49506100#49506100

Comment: @NileshRathod The gradle-make aware is already present in my project configurations

Comment: Does maven repository exist in your  project build gradle file?

Comment: @0xalihn no it's not there

Comment: check my answer below

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510176/android-studio-gradle-sync-failed-could-not-head-received-status-code-5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is on the jcenter side, see http://status.bintray.com

> Intermittent download failures
>   Identified - There is an intermittent download failures due to an issue with CDN provider. CDN provider is investigating the issue. 
>   Mar 17, 21:29 UTC

Answer (score 4):

Update your Project build gradle file with maven repo like below and check:

```
  repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
      maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
      maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
      }
}
```

Also try with this changes if doesn't work

```
repositories {
    jcenter {
        url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
    }
}


repositories {
    maven  {
        url "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2"
    }
}
```

Comment: not working bro. still same error

Comment: Also try to update the gradle wrapper to latest version 2.4

Comment: I have 4.4 gradle version

Comment: My answer updated try with updated changes.

Comment: yes, i am trying

Answer (score 1):

> After updating the Android Studio to 3.1.0

I just had the same problem, I resolved it using

```
maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
to the TopMost buildScript like this in project-level gradle :-

 buildscript {
    repositories {
      .....
      ...
     maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
     }
```

> For reference take a sample of the project-level gradle:-

```
buildscript {

  repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
      maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
      maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
      }
}
 dependencies {
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
     classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.24.4'

     // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
     // in the individual module build.gradle files
   }
}

 allprojects {
   repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()      
   }
 }

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Also in gradle-wrapper.properties use this :-

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip

instead of 4.1-all.zip
```