# Android Studio: Gradle sync failed: Could not HEAD '...'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

After update Android Studio to latest version (3.1) and gradle version in my project I get an error (the link is always different):

```
12:54   Gradle sync started

12:56   Gradle sync failed: Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/analytics-library/shared/26.1.0/shared-26.1.0.jar'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway             Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (1m 56s 602ms)

12:56   Gradle sync started

12:57   Gradle sync failed: Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/codehaus/mojo/animal-sniffer-parent/1.14/animal-sniffer-parent-1.14.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway             Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (1m 4s 266ms)

12:58   Gradle sync started

12:59   Gradle sync failed: Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/sun/activation/all/1.2.0/all-1.2.0.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway          Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (1m 29s 985ms)

13:01   Gradle sync started

13:02   Gradle sync failed: Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/sun/activation/javax.activation/1.2.0/javax.activation-1.2.0.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway            Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (4s 976ms)
```

Android Studio version:

```
Android Studio 3.1
Build #AI-173.4670197, built on March 22, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

I already tried clean rebuild and update gradle, restart Android Studio and PC, but without success. Any ideas?

PS: of course I have internet. Also, if you open a link in the browser - the file is downloaded.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49506100/4762767

Comment: Try to update your project build gradle version with latest one required for 3.1

Comment: I think this could be a temporary network issue, I just kept pressing try again, with a different error each time. It eventually synced.

Comment: After each gradle or studio updating, developers are facing with gradle syncing problems

Comment: @DenisMakovsky this is the first serious problem after update that I encountered. I have never seen such critical problems before.

Comment: It's nothing to do with the update though...

Answer (score 82, accepted):

jcenter is having issues at the moment, please check http://status.bintray.com/

**EDIT**: it looks like the link above was [sunset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70687500/1401164), new link at: https://status.gradle.com/

Comment: Today there is no issue.
"Identified - There is an intermittent download failures due to an issue with CDN provider. CDN provider is investigating the issue. 
Mar 17, 21:29 UTC"
This issue occurred on Mar 17 not today.

Comment: They have updated the system status now

Comment: Intermittent download issues in Bintray is detected (Y)

Comment: While the outage is happening, this can be done: Android Studio -> Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle -> Check "Offline Work".

Comment: It is having issues for Europe right now.. :( But I was persistent - I kept running `react-native run-android` until everything was installed ':D

Comment: Who's here in March 2021?

Comment: Who's here in December 2021??

Comment: Still 502 in Jan 2022

Comment: when will it get fixed

Comment: 502 for https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.3.72/kotlin-reflect-1.3.72.pom here. but only from my github action

Comment: Getting same issue since evening.. Does any one have a permanent solution for this problem?

Comment: Getting this today also, and even this answer's linked status site gives 502 currently when navigated to. `Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway`
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml gives 502 error currently.  The solution is to wait until the host of this jcenter bintray website figures out and resolves their issue.

Comment: Upon further research, JCenter and Bintray in early 2021 announced their package hosting would be removed completely as package sources, and anything using such a package source will need to find another package host to get that package from by Feb 1st 2022.  The announcement is at https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/ .  **However**, that announcement has a more recent update at the top that states `UPDATE 4/27/2021: We listened to the community and will keep JCenter as a read-only repository indefinitely.`.

Comment: After communicating with someone from JFrog, it seems that Bintray has been fully and permanently decommissioned, while JConnect should still be available indefinitely as a readonly repository.

Comment: we have multiple repositories. why would it fail and halt completely instead of switching to the next one...

Comment: JFrog seems to have resolved this issue (for JCenter) as of this morning (1/13/22).  I was able to again access the package I needed to from JCenter in my build process. @SambhavKhandelwal It might be worth checking again today.

Comment: yeah, works fine!

Comment: Anybody else having trouble again today (Jan 17 2022)?

Comment: Yes I have the exact same issue today.

Comment: @adiohaion Okay, thanks for confirming. At least it's not just me. This wasn't a problem I wanted to solve today... FFS.

Comment: Its ok now, managed to compile.

Answer (score 40):

> After updating the Android Studio to 3.1.0 ,

I just had the same problem, i resolved it using

```
 maven {   url "https://maven.google.com"  }
```

to the **TopMost** `buildScript` like this in *project-level gradle*  :-

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
      .....
      ...
     maven {   url "https://maven.google.com"   }
```

> For reference take a **sample** of the project-level gradle:-

```
buildscript {

  repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
      maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
      maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
      mavenCentral()
      maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
      maven {  url "https://maven.google.com"  }
  }
 dependencies {
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
     classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.24.4'
   }
}

 allprojects {
   repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()      
   }
 }

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Note** :- One more thing:-

In **`gradle-wrapper.properties`** use this :-

```
  distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

*Instead* of `4.1-all.zip` .

**Edit** :- If you want to resolve the issue fast , you can also try adding these - according to *Omar's* answer :-

```
 maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/riteshakya037/maven" }
```

along with

```
  maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
```

Comment: Has also been the solution for me.

Comment: Not working for me. :(

Comment: Gradle sync failed: Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle-api/26.1.0/lint-gradle-api-26.1.0.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

Comment: Lion Heart. Getting the same issue but on Jenkins server.

Comment: It seems that there is some sort of network error on jcenter

Comment: change in gradle-wrapper.properties fixed my problem.

Comment: Thanks, when I add ``` maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/riteshakya037/maven" }```, It solves my problem.

Comment: Changing the project's repos to the ones on your sample solved it for me. This should be the accepted answer as it clearly details how to solve the issue.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to everyone for the quick answers!

It seems like temporary network issues on the "jcenter.bintray.com" website. I just clicked "Try Again" many times and in the end everything was updated.

Also, if you open the links in the browser - from time to time you will receive a "Service Error" message. So the problem is not on your side.

Answer (score 9):

**Tip:**
When you get your project to build correctly the once **enable offline-mode** so AS don't have to connect to jcenter every gradle refresh.

[image]

Comment: Wow I don't know what I would have done if this didn't work.  What a disaster this android studio and gradle/maven stuff is.  Such a crappy build platform.

Answer (score 8):

Ok, I slove it by:

In your **build.gradle** project level, add this:

```
buildscript {
    ...
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0' // Updated from 3.0 to 3.1.0

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}}
```

Note that I've updated **gradle** from 3.0 to 3.1.0

**Next:** add the same previous links to **allprojects's repository** body:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
```

}

**One more thing**:

In **gradle-wrapper.properties** use this :

**distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip**

After that, just sync again, and it will work.

Answer (score 3):

For me after applying [Santanu Sur's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49510333/2294985) The error hapenned again but with another library
I have check project's gradle and I found this line 
    `maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/riteshakya037/maven" }` in

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/riteshakya037/maven" }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

I deleted it, and everything is good now

Comment: Thanks, I solve it with the code ` maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/riteshakya037/maven" }`

Comment: This link is Forbidden now. Any fix for that. I'm using "http://dl.bintray.com/lukaville/maven". But it is also forbidden and fails to build. @N.bin

Answer (score 2):

I've just clicked **Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project** and Android Studio downloaded all the needed files.

Comment: tried this as well but didnt resolve the issue

Comment: didn't work for me either

Answer (score 1):

It's a server response error. Keep trying by pressing "Try Again" after some time. It will be ok automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling and Download & install from Developer site solved the issue for me.