# Android Studio update 3.1 start getting 502 Gate way gradle dependecies error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.1

After update that SDK on my Jenkin server. I am getting below console error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'BuildDevelop'.

  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not resolve io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :
  >   Could not resolve io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+.
  >   Failed to list versions for io.fabric.tools:gradle.
  >   Could not list versions using M2 pattern 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-revision.[ext]'.
  >   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/fabric/tools/gradle/'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/fabric/tools/gradle/'.
  >   Read timed out
- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: Please show the `repositories` block of your build file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jcenter 502 bad gateway after gradle refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55276770/jcenter-502-bad-gateway-after-gradle-refresh)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is because bintray is down: http://status.bintray.com

Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49510333/1607169

Comment: Not working for me. Every time build failed on Jenkins.

Comment: That incident happened on May 27.

Comment: there is still info `Downloads   Major Outage`. Adding `maven {url "https://maven.google.com"}` to `buildscript` will help, you just need to be patient and try to sync it few times. `./gradlew --recompile-scripts --continue` will sync grade from command line

Answer (score 0):

It's not so good idea, but you can revert `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0` to **`3.0.1`**
And
 **`gradle-4.1-all.zip`** in `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip` in **`gradle-wrapper.properties`**

Answer (score 0):

Update your Project build gradle file with maven repo and proper jcenter like below and check:

```
  repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
      jcenter { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
      maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
      maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
      maven { url "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2" }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running into a similar error and upgraded gradle to version 4.4 and that resolved the gradle sync issues.

You can [follow this guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#updating-gradle) to upgrade, or go to `File > Project Structure > Project` and enter in `4.4` for the `Gradle version`

My projet gradle files looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.31'
    ext.anko_version='0.10.4'
    ext.supportLibVersion = '27.0.2'

    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```