# jcenter 502 bad gateway after gradle refresh

Tags: java, gradle, jcenter

Unable to connect to jcenter address 
https://jcenter.bintray.com/

Got an 502 Bad Gateway response

[image]

And also in my intellj IDE after I click gradle refresh

```
Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/jnr/jffi/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
```

Anyone knows what happened?

Comment: maybe the site is under maintenance, try again later.

Comment: yeah I can connected to it now, thank you

Comment: CONFIGURE FAILED in 2s
ERROR: Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.21/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.21.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project 
same issue from IST 1.00pm.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Bin tray is experiencing "intermittent issues" on their download network : https://status.bintray.com/

[image]

Comment: This is affecting any travis CI build that uses the ubuntu trusty distro. The builds fail during apt get update. And probably all kinds of other build systems

Comment: Just experienced the same error today, Bintray is currently investigating this issue (Intermittent download issues in Bintray from Europe)

Comment: Bintray is now sunsetted - https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/

Comment: Bintray is supposedly permanently sunsetted at this point.

Comment: so, what is the alternate now ?

Comment: The sunset and it's impact on Jetbrains software is discussed [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2021/04/migration-from-bintray/). The way I read that is that you have two options: upgrade to a 2020.3 or newer version, or if that is not possible use a cache redirector which they discuss in the comments on the post.

Answer (score -9):

suggest you can remove jcenter(),and config aliyun maven

```
maven { 
  url 'http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/' 
}

maven { 
  url 'http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/repositories/jcenter'
}
```

Comment: These are not official repos. Thay can contain hacked jars.