# Gradle is failing to retrieve kotlin standard library

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I keep getting this message in my build:

```
Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.71/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.71.jar'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
```

It's weird because my Kotlin version is not even `1.3.71`, it's this:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.21"
...
}
```

My android studio version:

```
Android Studio 4.1.1
Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.6953283, built on November 4, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.15.7
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 2014M
Cores: 4
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true, external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: IdeaVIM, org.jetbrains.kotlin
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jcenter 502 bad gateway after gradle refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55276770/jcenter-502-bad-gateway-after-gradle-refresh)

Comment: Well it's the same problem because of their server being down, but that question is old. It's worth to keep this up because they went on a scheduled maintenance again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be fixed now.

Just checked and I am able to download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.71/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.71.jar

Answer (score 1):

jcenter download is under maintenance. Subscribe to https://status.bintray.com/ for further updates.

Answer (score 1):

jcenter is having issues at the moment, please check http://status.bintray.com/
You can wait till they fix the issue

Comment: Well how long does this usually take? are there other repositories other than jcenter that I can use in the meantime?

Comment: It must be fixed by now