# Bintray web site down all day is it permanent issue?

Tags: android, jcenter

I updated my Android studio to Artic Fox 2021.3.1 and in order to clean the project I cleaned the project and try to run again.

Almost 10 hours the http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven is down and Android studio is crashing.

[image]

When I checked the site https://status.bintray.com/ it said "Thanks for supporting Bintray! This service has now been sunset."

[image]

I check the question below, it seems there was problem past days but the status wasa different so I am not sure that this issue will be permanent? And if it is permanent, what will we do create new projects.

[jcenter 502 bad gateway after gradle refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55276770/jcenter-502-bad-gateway-after-gradle-refresh)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the problem comes from this "The JFrog Security research team has found found 17 malicious packages in the npm (Node.js package manager) repository. Many of them intentionally seek to attack a users’ Discord token"

You can see it in https://jfrog.com/blog/malicious-npm-packages-are-after-your-discord-tokens-17-new-packages-disclosed/

The same day it happened they suspended the service..

In my experience, this Bintray is down, it already happened, it usually takes about two days, but as @Roman answer says, I hope they fix it soon.

Comment: @Magnus You can see it

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any mention in that blog post of a connection to the `502 Bad Request` outage of `google.bintray.com`? What makes you think there is a connection? The bintray server was down a week ago as well, then came back online.

Comment: @Magnus That is why I say that it is apparent, it is not necessary for a 502 to appear because the server is down due to this problem, Jfrog has not given more information than that, only the maintenance of the server, that is why it is apparent since it is logical that due to a problem so you need to check the packages or affect the artifacts. A few weeks ago Jfrog bintray was fine, then the server is down due to maintenance problems, now it is likely because of this event that happened ...

Comment: The servers are still down and the project is not building. What is the solution to continue for working?  @Nautilus

Comment: @Olkunmustafa I sent an email yesterday and this was the answer.
"As stated in the blog post, Bintray will be discontinued indefinitely and will not be a functional tool as we migrate the Bintray toolset to Artifactory." .Personally, it affects me because I use flutter packages, and these repositories are searched for by google.bintray in which as it is down the server does not work, I don't know if google would look for a solution, at the moment in my project I had to disable the dependencies that require bintray.

Comment: One option that I am trying, is to remove google () in the repositories and replace them with mavenCentral (), I have not tried it but for the moment it is my only option personally since 10 days have passed and the server is down, if they repair it Apparently they will take longer, everything is complex and they do not give information...

Comment: Any luck with workaround? Replacing google () with mavenCentral () do not work for me.

Comment: @Pavel Update my question, try this [my question ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70309075/problems-in-android-repository-flutter-tensorflow-lite-by-bintray-502?noredirect=1#comment124315942_70309075)

Answer (score -1):

Intermittent download issues in Bintray. Will be resolved soon.

Comment: Thank you for answer :)

Comment: How do you know? A link to some source would be nice.

Comment: It is 13 of Dec, repo still down.

Comment: @Olkunmustafa Update my question, try this [my question ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70309075/problems-in-android-repository-flutter-tensorflow-lite-by-bintray-502?noredirect=1#comment124315942_70309075)