# How to fix project after Android Studio Update 3.1 ??

Tags: android, gradle

I've got this errors:

Gradle sync failed: Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6/commons-codec-1.6.jar'. 
Received status code 504 from server: Gateway Time-out

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (1m 58s 584ms)  >> also not working

I like Android Studio Updates ... always a challenge

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510176/android-studio-gradle-sync-failed-could-not-head-received-status-code-5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio: Gradle sync failed: Could not HEAD '...'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510176/android-studio-gradle-sync-failed-could-not-head-received-status-code-5)

Answer (score 0):

There's major outage of Bintray downloads server: http://status.bintray.com/, try to sync your project in a few hours

Comment: Thanks!

..  I now have to look for a downgrade while it stil not possible to work ....and customers waiting