# Gradle sync failed with Android Studio 3.1: Uninitialized object exists on backward branch 70

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

After Updating Android Studio from 3.0 to 3.1 My project gradle syncing failed with the following error.

```
Gradle sync failed: Uninitialized object exists on backward branch 70 Exception Details: Location: 
com/android/build/gradle/tasks/BuildArtifactReportTask.newArtifact(Lcom/android/build/api/artifact/BuildableArtifact;)
Lcom/android/build/gradle/tasks/BuildArtifactReportTask$BuildableArtifactData;
```

Comment: Read this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510176/android-studio-gradle-sync-failed-could-not-head-received-status-code-5/49511911#49511911

Answer (score 76):

As @tech_android already posted in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49515100/gradle-sync-failed-with-android-studio-3-1-uninitialized-object-exists-on-backw#comment86058048_49518396), to solve that problem permanently, go to Module Settings `>` SDK Location `>` Use embedded JDK.

This will remove dependency on the external Java installation by using the embedded JDK.

[image: Remove dependency on the external JAVA installation by using the embedded JDK.]

Comment: I always spend an hour to resolve such a stupid problem instead of looking for the right answer on SO. Thanks!

Comment: You can find the above window by clicking **File** > **Project Structure**.

Answer (score 10):

This is a bug of JDK old versions i guess. Go to the project structure and change your project to latest JDK like 1.80_72 or later versions.

Hopefully it will fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks @0xalihn for your reply. I use embedded JDK of Android studio and its working fine.

Comment: Faced with the same issue and this advice helped.

Answer (score 6):

It's resolved my issue when **I used embedded JDK(recommended)** option

**Do this**:

**Project Structure -> SDK Location -> Select "Use embedded JDK(recommended)"**

Answer (score 5):

1) Update to the latest JDK Version, in my case jdk1.8.0_162

2) In your Android Studio select File-> Project Structure -> SDK Location -> JDK Location, write the directory C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162

3) Restart Android Studio

Problem Solved

Comment: Thanks @melhito for your reply. I use embedded JDK of Android studio and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio:  3.5.3
gradle plugin:   3.5.3
gradle:          5.4.1
platform:        Mac OS Mojave 10.14.6 (18G103)

I had done this:Project Structure -> SDK Location -> Select "Use embedded JDK(recommended)"
but it still not working.

when I read this [article](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#build_environment),

you can add a property at gradle.properies:

**org.gradle.java.home=(path to JDK home)**

it works!