# Getting SHA1 in flutter issue

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to get SHA1 for firebase in flutter. I have tried the command ./gradlew app:signingReport in both vs code and android studio, but I am getting the following error. Also, I have tried to get SHA1 by opening build.gradle file in android studio and followed the required steps. But every time I get the following error.

```
Uninitialized object exists on backward branch 45
```

Exception Details:

Location:
com/android/tools/build/jetifier/core/proguard/ProGuardTypesMap.([Lkotlin/Pair;)V @101: goto

Reason:
Error exists in the bytecode

Bytecode:

```
0000000: 2b12 ffb8 00d2 2a2b 4d3a 0d03 3e2c 3a04

0000010: bb00 7359 2cbe b700 7ac0 007c 3a05 0336
0000020: 0619 043a 0719 07be 3608 0336 0915 0915
0000030: 08a2 0037 1907 1509 323a 0a19 0519 0a3a
0000040: 0b3a 0e03 360c 190b b601 1319 0bb6 0116
0000050: b800 f8b8 00b5 3a0f 190e 190f b900 a902
0000060: 0057 8409 01a7 ffc8 1905 c000 ab3a 0e19
0000070: 0d19 0ec0 009c b800 b9b7 0060 b1
```

Comment: What result did you try to get and what is your code that caused error?

Comment: What you are trying to do? Add a description to your question body

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gradle sync failed: Uninitialized object exists on backward branch 70](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50852086/gradle-sync-failed-uninitialized-object-exists-on-backward-branch-70)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by uninstalling the jdk 8 version completely and downloaded-installed new jdk-8u202-windows-x64.exe version from the official site.https://www.oracle.com/in/java/technologies/javase/javase8-archive-downloads.html