# Android Studio 3.1 : updating gradle file cause android studio to freeze

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle, android-studio-3.1

Today I updated Android studio from 3.0.1 to 3.1.

I encountered a weird issue with Gradle. Each time I tried to edit a .gradle file, Android Studio freezes.

With some research, I saw that each time you edit a .gradle file, Android Studio send a request to search "http://search.maven.org/".

I'm behind a proxy at my work, everything is configured, everything worked properly before that update.

Is anyone encountered the same issue with this version or a older one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jcenter is having issues so when you get your project to build correctly the once enable offline-mode so AS don't have to connect to jcenter every gradle refresh.

see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49510176/3998402) for more info.

Comment: Thank you. When i make some research yesterday i didn't find this question.

Answer (score 2):

It is always good to check idea.log to see if there are any errors. On Mac OS X you can use "Help" > "Show Log in Finder" to show the idea.log file.

For my case, I found errors below, where my proxy was failing because I have just changed my password. After I updated my password, the freezing issue went away.

```
WARN - roid.inspections.LintIdeClient - Could not connect to maven central to look up the latest available version for com.google.android:flexbox:+
WARN - roid.inspections.LintIdeClient - Could not connect to maven central to look up the latest available version for com.google.android:flexbox:+
```

Comment: Tips like this are always usefull. Thank you for sharing this ChinLoong !

Answer (score 0):

update maven gradle plugin in **build.gradle** using below

```
classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.0'
```

In **gradle-wrapper.properties** use this :

```
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

and update **buildToolsVersion** to 27.0.3