# Android Studio 3.1 stuck at Configure Build over 30 Minutes

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-studio-3.1

So I just updated my Android Studio to 3.1 from 3.0.1. As I am typing this, over 30 minutes have been passed and Android Studio is stuck at **Configure build**.
What have I done:

1. change gradle version in project gradle file
2. checked my internet (it is working fine)

Below is a snapshot of my screen with internet results
[image: image showing internet stats along with build log]

These dependencies in particular are taking all the time.
[image: further build logs]

My project build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And here is my application build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.smk.carsapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module: 'okhttp'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.5.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    implementation 'com.jsibbold:zoomage:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.siclo.ezphotopick:library:1.0.8'
    //    TEST
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://dl.bintray.com/siclo/SicloAndroidOSS'
    }
}
```

Comment: wait until it finishes, yesterday when I update mine studio, it took around 30-40 for updation.

Comment: you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510176/android-studio-gradle-sync-failed-could-not-head-received-status-code-5/49510333#49510333 if you want to resolve fast !!

Comment: @Lucifer I waited for over an hour and then I cancelled. I don't think that would've been helpful.

Comment: @SantanuSur Looks like it might resolve my issue. Currently downloading gradle-4.4-all.zip will update after it is finished

Comment: @SantanuSur Thank you very much. changing 4.1 to 4.4 fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixed:**
I changed the `distributionUrl` in `gradle-wrapper.properties` as pointed by Santanu [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49510333/6594057).

> In gradle-wrapper.properties use this :-
>
> `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip`
>
> Instead of 4.1-all.zip .

Answer (score 1):

try this :

**Android Studio go to File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle**

Check the 'Offline work' under 'Global Gradle settings'

It will reduce 80% gradle build time.

[image]

and check gradle dependencies

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha9'
 }
 }
```

Add dexOption and give the following heapSize

```
dexOptions {
incremental = true;
preDexLibraries = false
javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Click to open ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ydhqb.png)

Enable Toggle Offline Mode Solved my issue. Check screenshot for more details.

Just select this one if it's not selected. its worked for me previously its take 25 30 minutes now it only takes a few seconds

Comment: Answers should be specific to the user. Please add some code so the author can replicate your solution. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: I just enabled offline mode.Check screenshot.