# Gradle project sync failed in android studio 3.1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

[image]my gradle.build contains

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and upon syncing project with gradle files is showing error as connection refused:connect .
There is a problem with Apply script build.gradle
Not able to resolve dependencies of classpath

Log file showing the below error

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.0/gradle-3.1.0.pom'.
at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:96)
```

Comment: add maven repo on your build gradle file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio: Gradle sync failed: Could not HEAD '...'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510176/android-studio-gradle-sync-failed-could-not-head-received-status-code-5)

Comment: Why Need to add maven repo ?? i mean in this Question @0xalihn

Comment: Cause its trying to download the resource from maven repository.

Comment: @0xalihn tried adding maven repo as well . Not working

Comment: I believe your problem must be resolved by now. I had the same problem too and it was because jcenter had a massive outage and gradle could not connect to repositories and download them.

Comment: Have you tried disabling offline mode?

Comment: I just restarted the IDE . It worked . Thanks a lot everyone

Answer (score 0):

Try using invalidate caches and restart in File Menu. Most of the time it works when studio have a new update.

Comment: Tried this as well.

Comment: Also try creating a new test project.

Answer (score 0):

Goto "File > Project Structure > SDK Location" menu and
Check "Use embedded JDK(recommended)".
It may be your JDK version problem.

Comment: I just restarted the IDE . It worked . Thanks a lot everyone