# jcenter repository disappeared

Tags: gradle, jcenter

I get an android source code with `org.litepal.android:java:3.0.0.` dependency, this dependency can be found in jcenter, according to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.litepal.android/java/3.0.0

I have a same error with other libraries.

I have commented the jCenter source in my build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
    mavenCentral()
    google()
    // jcenter()
}
```

I get a following error message:

````
   > Could not find org.simple:androideventbus:1.0.5.1.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find org.litepal.android:java:3.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find cn.bingoogolapple:bga-progressbar:1.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :app
    ```
````

Comment: Answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70689114/8511982

Comment: I have added https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/repo repository to my sources, but it says: `Could not find org.litepal.android:java:3.0.0`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74260926/could-not-head-https-jcenter-bintray-com-com-facebook-react-react-native-mave)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, jcenter is down and no library located there is available right now.

I checked out your library (org.litepal.android) and it seems that particular version isn't available from any other repository. However, I found out that the developer published another version of that library (https://github.com/guolindev/LitePal) and maybe you can change it.

I would advice you to change your reference:

- org.litepal.android:java:3.0.0.

To:

- org.litepal.guolindev:core:3.2.3

Hope it works for you!