# Run button isn't compiling project in Android Studio 3.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.1

I have just upgraded to Android Studio 3.1 on macOS Sierra and now when I press "Run" button it runs the app on my Android device without compiling new code changes. Is there a bug in Android Studio 3.1 or I am missing something?

Please help. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: How do you know it did not compile? Please screenshot your android studio

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49505929/android-studio-3-1-gradle-unexpected-behaviour/49506100#49506100

Comment: did you get any error while compiling?

Comment: No I am not getting any error but the latest changes made in a code for e.g. new Logging lines don't show in the Logcat section.

Comment: Akshay Katariya thanks for the link, adding "Gradle-awake" in Run configurations solved the problem for me.