# Android Studio does not change my code after run

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a weird problem with Android Studio. When I Run my app there are **no gradlebuild** and etc. just installing app and launch activity which means nothing what I changed in the code will be changed in my apk.

Have you any idea why is this happening?

project level gradle:

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.30'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.0.0"
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app level gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions' 
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId ""
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
realm {
    syncEnabled = true;
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: try rebuild code and run

Comment: thanks :) I have tried clean, rebuild, invalidate cashes and restart a thousend times. I have reinstalled and updated everything.

Comment: did you try with log

Comment: yeah I have these two issues: 

`Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018`



`Configuration 'provided' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'compileOnly'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018`

Comment: But there is nothing I can do with this. If I use 'Make project' and after Run then sometimes my code does work but sometimes doesn't.

Comment: can you post you gradle file

Comment: Disable Instant Run

Comment: I posted my gradles.

Comment: disable instant run does not have any effect

Comment: Reboot computer and device, reconnect, run. If it doesn't do it then, try uninstall of app and run to install fresh.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce thanks it's solved my problem!!

Comment: I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49505929/android-studio-3-1-run-not-compiling-code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to fix the Run process in Android Studio.

Look at your main toolbar and find this box:
[image]

Click the box and select `Edit Configurations...`.

Make sure the window has the following items in `Before launch` section:

- Gradle-aware Make
- Instant App Provision

[image]

Click OK.

Run your app.

Comment: I think this was fixed in Android Studio 3.1.

Comment: Thanks this is the solution!

Comment: Just adding `Gradle-aware Make` works for v2021.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Try to following instruction it will surely help you. I already face same problem before couple of month.

* Update ADB in your `Android Studio`.

* Uninstall application.

* Restart adb start-server.

* Restart you testing device.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: **File menu -> Invalidate Caches/ Restart**. I think it will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's been an issue in the 3.1.0 build tools upgrade of Android Studio. Follow these steps to resolve it.

1. **Select Run and click Edit Configurations**

   **Make sure, Gradle-aware Make is Added in TaskList or not. If not then:**
2. **click +**
3. **select Gradle-aware Make**
4. **Leave the task empty and select OK**

**NOTE: Make sure Gradle-aware Make is before Instant App Provision**