# Does Android Studio automatically build before running?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

When I add a line of code such as:

```kotlin
println(1)
```

Then run the app, sometimes this line of code doesn't seem to take effect.

I found that Android Studio will not build before running? How should this problem be solved?

I've tried setting `Build` in `launch before` in `Edit Configure`, but it fails every time with various errors, while when I manually `build` again it succeeds.

Comment: Check out this answer, it might help you to solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/49506100/14034353

Comment: @LukuGeraud This is not the same as in my case, I added `Gradle-aware Make`. And I would like to know more about the principles of `build` and `Run`.