# app-debug.apk does not exist on disk. Error while Installing APK

Tags: android, apk

Hello everyone trying to launch my app (which has always worked until today !!!) continues to present this error:

> The APK file C:\Users\User\Documents\App 0.0\Dooale\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk does not exist on disk.
>   Error while Installing APK

I tried to verify on my PC in the indicated path: C: \ Users \ User \ Documents \ App 0.0 \ Dooale \ app \ build \ outputs \ and actually does not exist !!!
In outputs there is only log !!!
How is it possible? What can I do?

Thank you all

Comment: You need to build your app before you can install it. This started happening with me too after most recent android studio update.
Click on Build then click on make project and it's done.

Comment: Yes indeed very good !! so how did you turn it? I've already done Sync Gradle and then Build> Rebuild Project but it did not work !!!

Comment: sorry mate, but that's all I did and it worked. You can try restarting studio or wait until someone finds a proper solution to your problem.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much the same

Comment: Do invalidate caches and restart your android studio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to solve these simple steps:

1 - I went to the android studio on Build -> Clean Project
      After waiting for it to end.
2 - I'm back on Build -> Rebuild Project

3 - I resynchronized with Gradle.

With these simple steps I managed to solve !!!

Comment: Have you been solving it for half of a year? :)

Comment: Thanks, this advice works in many scenarious. I tried to invalidate caches and clean a project, but it hadn't helped. After rebuilding the project APK has been built.

Answer (score 0):

This stupid error wasted a whole day of research.

Recently I have replaced REST library `Fuel` with `Retrofit` and added `OkHttp` logging interceptor with it's `Proguard` rules. Then I removed interceptor but forgot to remove Proguard rules.

This error appeared in the next day. I couldn't build a project, even reinstalled AS. Then I built an `apk` with `Build > Generate Signed Bundle / APK`. There I saw warnings:

> AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Missing class:
>   android.arch.paging.PositionalDataSource","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
>
> AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"The rule `-keep public class *extends
>   androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelable {\n 
>   \u003cinit\u003e();\n}` uses extends but actually matches
>   implements.","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"} AGPBI:
>   {"kind":"warning","text":"Type `org.conscrypt.Conscrypt` was not
>   found, it is required for default or static interface methods
>   desugaring of `void
>   okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform.configureSslSocketFactory(javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory)`","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.squareup.okhttp3\okhttp\3.12.0\b36f4a04584c0fb0d9af2d3401cdff8dacb1ea54\okhttp-3.12.0.jar"}],"tool":"D8"}

Then I removed unnecessary lines from Proguard. See [How to resolve D8 warning: D8: Type `org.conscrypt.Conscrypt` was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49880928/how-to-resolve-d8-warning-d8-type-org-conscrypt-conscrypt-was-not-found/54869945#54869945).

UPDATE

After several hours a problem disappeared even if I reverted to previous commits. Also it didn't reproduce on another PC. Android Studio is weird.

In order not to rebuild the project every time at every change in code I added this to configuration (see [Android Studio not deploying changes to app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312900/android-studio-not-deploying-changes-to-app/49525674#49525674)).

[image]

UPDATE 2

I use Retrofit and keep all response files (JSON structures) in one package. I had to add them to `proguard-rules.pro`:

```
-keep class com.example.data.network.model.** { *; }
```

If I remove this line, an application won't compile with message: "AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Missing class: android.arch.paging.PositionalDataSource","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}".