# How to resolve D8 warning: D8: Type `org.conscrypt.Conscrypt` was not found

Tags: okhttp

```
/Volumes/SSD/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/3.10.0/7ef0f1d95bf4c0b3ba30bbae25e0e562b05cf75e/okhttp-3.10.0.jar: D8: Type `org.conscrypt.Conscrypt` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform.buildIfSupported()`
```

Comment: I'm running into the same error. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I'm getting something similar: `AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Type \`libcore.io.Memory\` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of \`void com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzyh$zzb.a(long, byte)\`","sources":[{"file":"/path/to/MyProject/app/build/intermediates/transforms/proguard/myvariant/release/0.jar"}],"tool":"D8"}`

Answer (score 18):

I was able to solve the problem with adding:

`-dontwarn okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform`

to the `proguard-rules.pro` file.

Comment: it seems that we are forcing the warning to go away, can you help me understand why exactly the warning is coming ?

Answer (score 5):

According to https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3922, it is safe to ignore these warnings.

If the build does not succeed, I suppose there is another problem.

Answer (score 4):

Probably https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/4604 will help, but I didn't try.

```
buildscript {
    ...
    repositories {
        ...
        maven {
            url 'http://storage.googleapis.com/r8-releases/raw'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools:r8:1.4.57'  // Must be before the Gradle Plugin for Android.
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'  // You don't need to upgrade this to use a newer R8 version.
        ...
     }
}
```

In my case I added OkHttp library and it's Proguard rules. Then removed the library but forgot to remove rules. You can comment or remove these lines from `proguard-rules.pro` if you removed OkHttp from `build.gradle`:

```
### OkHttp.

# JSR 305 annotations are for embedding nullability information.
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**

# A resource is loaded with a relative path so the package of this class must be preserved.
-keepnames class okhttp3.internal.publicsuffix.PublicSuffixDatabase

# Animal Sniffer compileOnly dependency to ensure APIs are compatible with older versions of Java.
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.*

# OkHttp platform used only on JVM and when Conscrypt dependency is available.
-dontwarn okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform
```

Answer (score -1):

From **./gradlew assemble**

> R8 is the new Android code shrinker. If you experience any issues,
>   please file a bug at https://issuetracker.google.com, using 'Shrinker
>   (R8)' as component name. You can disable R8 by updating
>   gradle.properties with 'android.enableR8=false'. Current version is:
>   1.4.94 (build 390954928f0db9c3b888a367f7f128ce3bbfb160 from go/r8bot (luci-r8-ci-archive-0-5g74)).