# Forced to restart & invalidate cache everytime i add/remove anything?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

It's a wierd issue i'm having. I have to press File > Invalidate caches and restart the entire program every time i change as much as one number.

The program won't update otherwise, i've tried to build the program etc. I also can't find anyone else having this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by the program won't update? Are changes not being reflected in your source code?

Comment: Yeah exactly that. I change X from 10 to 15 but for it to actually change and display on the screen i'm forced to restard and reinvalidate cache.

Comment: Try to follow the description given by Sira Lam here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312900/android-studio-not-deploying-changes-to-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue your dealing with can happen for several reasons, mainly, what you MUST avoid is:

Do not create new files while running the app on either simulator or real phone. New layout files, new classes, etc.

Make sure, your are not running the app before you create new files, add new drawable, for exemple.