# Coding changes is not reflected in app from Android studio

Tags: android, kotlin

I clean,Rebuild code & Invalid cache but coding changes is not reflected in Android Studio 4.0

Comment: Which Gradle version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue with one of the earlier Android studio releases. I have solved by updating the Gradle version. It may be solved your issue.

Comment: Also check any of the solution provided here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312900/android-studio-not-deploying-changes-to-app/49525674#:~:text=In%20Android%20Studio%203.6.,Deployment%20and%20check%20the%20checkboxes.&text=If%20you%20do%2C%20you%20might%20be%20changing%20one%20and%20deploying%20another.